# Android studio Gradle Wrapper Incompatible version

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

[image]

Issue. Every time we update android studio and tools we end up on a new version of the gradle pluging. The team has to manually update the build.gradle every time we switch branches.

Solution use gradle wrappers. However it is failing to work giving us this incompatible error. The wrapper in past experiences would download the version we want and just work. Why are we getting this incompatible version?

Most of us use canary channels for studio and tools. However we want the build.gradle to be the same for all of us and not to have to mess with it.

Specifically I do not want to have to update

**classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha7'**

I also want to avoid using something like gradle:2.2+ as the goal is to have everyone on the same set of tools.

Top most build.gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.2' //version required
//    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha7'

        // Per https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

Comment: if you would set classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.14.0' it would still get error or just give up and no dialogs

Comment: We can't find 2.14.0 Looks like its not in jcenter. http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/
Following I cannot increase the version for distributionUrl else I get an error explicitly saying to lower it to 2.14.1